# yield return and return

Tags: c#, yield, yield-return

I often find myself writing sth. like this:

```
if (condition)
{
  yield return whatever;
  yield break;
}
```

I find it quite verbose to have to use two yield statements for the standard paradigm "return one value and exit method". I know I can just `return new List<type>() { whatever };` but that would defeat the benefit of using yield in the rest of the method.

Is there a more elegant way to `yield return` a value and exit the method?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably your only other option.

```
if (condition) 
{
    yield return 1;
}
else
{
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
}
```

Comment: Hm, since I like to exit early, this seems like no real alternative.